Need help with picture scaling and alignment
I would like to add 2 pictures at the bottom of the page; the one on the right is close to the margin, while the one on the left is right up to the edge of the page.I have tried \minipage and \tabular but I can't seem to get the right position that I want.
Here are the codes that I used:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for inserting images


\begin{document}

\thispagestyle{empty}

\begin{flushright}
    \textbf{\huge{SS XXX-X:YYYY}} \\
    \large{(ICS XX.XXX.XX; XX.XXX)}
\end{flushright}

\vspace{3cm}

\textbf{\Large{SINGAPORE STANDARD}} \vspace{1em}

\textbf{\Huge{SS XXX-X:YYYY}} \vspace{1em}

\huge{– Part X : Part title Xxxx} \vspace{2em}

\Large{Incorporating Amendment No. 1 and No. 2 } \vspace{1em}

\Large{Confirmed and classified as a mature standard YYYY }

\vfill

\begin{flushleft}

\includegraphics[width=5cm, height=4cm]{BigS.png}

\end{flushleft}

\begin{flushright}
     \includegraphics[scale=1]{SSC.jpg}
\end{flushright}

\end{document}

*** I have added a picture of the final product that I want to achieve.

The same question with the same images was asked the other day. Was that you? Is this some exercise?

There are no enough context to answer properly. The images shoul be only in this  page or in every page in a long document?  It couild be more text that the showed or is onya a title page without text? In the first case, the text should overlap the big image? The ansewer could be fifferent in each case.  Please explain.

Yes, it is the same question. I was told that my question wasn't clear enough and that I should include the codes I used in the question as well.

@Fran This is supposed to be the cover page of a document. The pictures are on this page only. My big issue is with the Big Red S logo on the lower left side that is seemingly cut off by half at the edge of the page.
